# how to order numbers stored as string in db by OrderBy function?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

How to order numbers stored as string in db by OrderBy function

```
mytable.OrderBy(s => s.Year);
```

for ex =>

- `string Year= 2013/2014`
- `string Year= 2017/2018`

Comment: Your strings look exactly like this: `"2013/2014"` ?

Comment: order by what logic ? The  lexicographic order used for strings should already work in your case, giving the same order as it would for numbers.

Comment: Unless you're concerned about years less than 1000 (or past 9999), ordering years as strings should have the same result as ordering them as integers. What's the issue?

Comment: Your strings look exactly like this: "2013/2014" ?  yes

Comment: Unless you're concerned about years less than 1000 (or past 9999), ordering years as strings should have the same result as ordering them as integers. What's the issue? I stored year column in db as string not integer

Comment: Very unclear. I.e. how one should compare `2013/2015` vs. `2012/2016` - there is no ordering of ranges... Maybe you have very specific case where string comparison would work. I.e. "school year" really should not be represented as string of two years but just one numerical year of when it starts - there are no school ears 2017/2025 usually...

Comment: What do the records in your db table look like?  Is the 2013/2014 one field on the database or the combination of two records?

Comment: @Rand You can order by strings, too. It will order them alphanumerically: numbers come before letters, A comes before B, and so on. What we're saying is, given your sample strings, the alpha order is the **same** as the numeric order. So again: what's the issue? When you try that code, what is broken? Is your real data not well represented by the sample data you provided? And if not, why would you think we could help with your problem without a representative sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to take the first year only:

```
s.Year.Trim().Substring(0, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are in a character column then they will sort as characters, not as numbers.

The only real workaround I know of would be to

- Either change that column to numeric data type, which you can't do if
  the values are '2013/2014'
- Create another numeric column that stores the numbers (i.e. 2013,
  2017) and then sort on that column.